# Create Database Table from this JSON

Tags: json

Can we create database table from this?

https://www.basicprimitives.com/usecases/firstfamilychart

I am using MYSQL database.

```
{ id: 1, title: "Thomas Williams", label: "Thomas Williams", description: "1", image: "images/photos/t.png"
},
{ id: 2, title: "Mary Spencer", label: "Mary Spencer", description: "2", image: "images/photos/m.png"
},
{ id: 3, title: "David Kirby", label: "David Kirby", description: "3", image: "images/photos/d.png"
},
{ id: 4, title: "Brad Williams", label: "Brad Williams", description: "4", image: "images/photos/b.png"
},
{ id: 5, title: "Mike Kirby", label: "Mike Kirby", description: "5", image: "images/photos/m.png"
},
{ id: 6, title: "Lynette Maloney", label: "Lynette Maloney", description: "6", image: "images/photos/m.png"
},
{ id: 7, title: "Sara Kemp", label: "Sara Kemp", description: "7", image: "images/photos/s.png"
},
{ id: 8, title: "Leon Kemp", label: "Leon Kemp", description: "8", image: "images/photos/l.png"
},
{ id: 9, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "Thomas Williams", label: "Thomas Williams", description: "1", image: "images/photos/t.png"
},
{ id: 10, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "Mary Spencer", label: "Mary Spencer", description: "2", image: "images/photos/m.png"
},
{ id: 11, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "David Kirby", label: "David Kirby", description: "3", image: "images/photos/d.png"
},
{ id: 12, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "Brad Williams", label: "Brad Williams", description: "4", image: "images/photos/b.png"
},
{ id: 13, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "Mike Kirby", label: "Mike Kirby", description: "5", image: "images/photos/m.png"
},
{ id: 14, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "Lynette Maloney", label: "Lynette Maloney", description: "6", image: "images/photos/m.png"
},
{ id: 15, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "Sara Kemp", label: "Sara Kemp", description: "7", image: "images/photos/s.png"
},
{ id: 16, parents: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ], title: "Leon Kemp", label: "Leon Kemp", description: "8", image: "images/photos/l.png"
}
```

This json generates following family tree

https://www.basicprimitives.com/usecases/firstfamilychart

Can i create database from this JSON?

Reason I need this: this is hard coded JSON data file. In reality ,
I want to create this from database.

If I know the reverse of this(JSON) i.e. database table structure,
from database table this JSON can be generated easily.

what I tried: https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator

I got following error
Parse error on line 1:

```
{ id: 0, parent: null,
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Same error when i tried:

- https://jsonlint.com/
- http://beautifytools.com/json-validator.php

Above JSON code is working properly
https://www.basicprimitives.com/usecases/firstfamilychart

Tried
https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-sql.htm
but getting error

> Array name or JSON not valid

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of all of your details, but... you'll need to parse the content being returned from that site, and then write code to insert that content into your database. And you'll also need to define the proper table(s) for your database.

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting is possible via NOSQL DB's like MongoDB which stores data in JSON format & you can retrieve it back in JSON format as well.

However if you use SQL databases, they expect the inputs to be in string format for SQL query. Hence you got your error when trying to store JSON instead of string directly. MongoDB accepts JSON as input.

Comment: Dear Norbert van Nobelen

thanks a lot for prompt reply.

Original data a is in MYSQL (around 15,000 records) 
so as to create family tree, I need to export to this format only then I can create the family tree .

In short it is not just storage of "this JSON"

to simplify this ,
 
above JSON data creates a family tree
refer following link
https://www.basicprimitives.com/usecases/firstfamilychart

i need to convert my data (15,000) records as per JSON data specified so as to create family tree

Comment: You can create crores of records in mongodb - no problem

Comment: I found out that this is NOT JSON

Comment: I found out that this is NOT JSON. This is some object in javascript. Wish  to know whether we can generate this programmatically

Comment: Yes you can still do this. However db allows only json type